# P2P on rtl8812au not working

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, wifi-direct, p2p

How to use P2P operations using rtl8812au driver?

I have tried almost every driver which are available out there in github and also in the linux home; none of them are actually working correctly.

The only driver which I found usable was `aircrack-ng-rtl8812au`

- https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

But for P2P group operations even that has some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily make the driver use `p2p_group_interface` by enabling the `RTW_P2P_GROUP_INTERFACE` macro to `1` in `os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h` file. I hope this helps you in some way.

Comment: will try this and come back , thank you geeker

Comment: Thank you so much @geeker it actually works with enabling the macro but has some errors while creating p2p group , if u are aware of the same can u help me out with this!.

Comment: @damadam I have specified in the question that p2p group operations has some issues I think it makes sense it ask the same.

Comment: I think the driver code has to changed w.r.t group interface , I'm not sure about it.

Comment: okay, thank you so much .